# How to change the value of submit button after click using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have dynamic page that fetch the data from database when clicked on submit button. I want to change the value of submit button when its clicked.

Show Data------> Refresh

```
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="showdata">Show Data</button>
```

when i clicked on this button once then it will its will hide and show

```
   <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="showdata">Refresh</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/priyasingh/t43vyyst/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).text( ($(this).text() == 'Show Data' ? 'Refresh' : 'Show Data') )
  })
```

})

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do:

```
$("#showdata").click(function() {
  $(this).text("Refresh");
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rur6g4es/)

Answer (score 0):

onclick event you can change the html text

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="showdata" onclick="changeHtml(this)">Show Data</button>

<script>
    function changeHtml(id) {
         id.innerHTML = "Refresh!";
    }
</script>
```

OR

Via jquery

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="showdata">Show Data</button>

<script>
    $( "#showdata" ).click(function() {
        $("#showdata").html('Refresh');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call that value because it has value already , just say text or innerHTML .

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById("showdata").onclick = function () {
        this.innerHTML = "Refresh";
     }
 </script>
```